# Two Conditions on MySQL WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My error is:
*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND (tblforecast.Issued like '%01-07%' ))order by tblforecast.Issued DESC' at line 2*

My code is:

```
$news = "SELECT tblforecast.Fore_ID, tblforecast.Issued, 
          tblforecast.Synopsis,tblforecast.Forecaster, tblusers.FirstName,
          tblusers.LastName FROM tblforecast 
             INNER JOIN tblusers ON tblusers.UserNumber = tblforecast.forecaster 
          WHERE ((tblforecast.Valid =$type) 
              AND (tblforecast.Issued like '%$filter%' ))
           order by tblforecast.Issued DESC";
```

If I only have one condition in my WHERE statement, it works.

$type is either 24 or 12. $filter is "mm-dd" in numeric form.

after this is executed, it will proceed to the displaying of the news which is:

```
$loadnews = mysql_query($news);

                if (!($loadnews))
                    echo mysql_error();

                while($waiting = mysql_fetch_array($loadnews))
                {
                    $NiD = $waiting['Fore_ID'];
                    $thedate = $waiting['Issued'];
                    $synop = $waiting['Synopsis'];
                    $forecaster = $waiting['FirstName']." ".$waiting['LastName'];

                    $dDate = strtotime($thedate);
                    $newDate = date('F j, Y',$dDate);
                    echo "<div class='well well-large'>
                            <p><b>$newDate</b>
                            <br><small><i>$forecaster</i></small>
                            <br>$synop</p>
                            <br><small><a href='pdetails.php?NiD=$NiD'>Read More</a></small></p>
                            </div>";                    
                }
```

---

In response to the requests for the content of `$news`, this is what it holds after the assignment statement:

```
SELECT tblforecast.Fore_ID, tblforecast.Issued, tblforecast.Synopsis,tblforecast.Forecaster, tblusers.FirstName, tblusers.LastName FROM tblforecast INNER JOIN tblusers ON tblusers.UserNumber = tblforecast.forecaster WHERE ((tblforecast.Valid =) AND (tblforecast.Issued like '%01-07%' ))order by tblforecast.Issued DESC
```

Comment: Are you using `&&` or `AND`, because the error message doesn't match the code you've posted

Comment: Your syntax is completely correct. So the problem is in your substitution variable, `$filter`

Comment: Seems like there's no syntax problem, your problem must be logical. If you can provide sql fiddle we can more likely be able to help

Comment: its either `$filter` or `$type` containing some un-escaped sequence

Comment: The error message and your code do not match

Comment: did you try to print out the value in the variable echo $news..

Comment: @shanavascet yes. it is working already. I just added a new feature which is the $filter (it's from another module which i decided to include in this)

Comment: @user2310289 sorry, i pasted the wrong error

Comment: Is the `$type` value quoted or not? Is it a string or a numeric value?

Comment: curious whether a space is needed before `order`

Comment: @MarkBaker agreed. I'm guessing he means for it to be a string, while this way it's checking it as a field

Comment: @MarkBaker $type is a number

Comment: How bout that ? $news="SELECT 
  tblforecast.Fore_ID, 
  tblforecast.Issued, 
  tblforecast.Synopsis,
  tblforecast.Forecaster, 
  tblusers.FirstName,
  tblusers.LastName 
 FROM 
  tblforecast INNER JOIN tblusers 
   ON tblusers.UserNumber = tblforecast.forecaster
    WHERE tblforecast.Valid = " . $type . "AND tblforecast.Issued LIKE '%" . $filter% . "' 
 ORDER BY tblforecast.Issued DESC";

Comment: Clary, @shanavascet is right, print out (and show us) what's in `$news` before trying to execute it.

Comment: if $type is a number that is a value in the DB, you must enclose it in single quotes, otherwise it is looking for a field with that name

Comment: @AndrewBrown never do that with an INTEGER, works fine. If you'll use single quotes, it will search for a VARCHAR

Comment: Clary, you've updated the question but _not_ with the content of `$news` - it's important to see what's actually going into there.

Comment: @Clary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: my mistake, it doesn't search for a field, but you are perfectly fine using quotes around an integer, and searching integer fields

Comment: Oh boy... please [read the red box](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect): `mysql_*` extension is _deprecated_, so don't use it. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead. Both support _prepared statements_, which will help you to fix that nasty injection vulnerability you have

Comment: @paxdiablo what do u mean content?

Comment: @Clary: what is `$type`, does it contain any quotes and what happens if you add a space to `=$type` => `= $type`?

Comment: Clary, in your code, immediately after you set `$news` (your first code snippet above), log it or print it out or otherwise save it so we can get a look at it.

Comment: @paxdiablo I guess this is what you meant, I echoed $news and displays: SELECT tblforecast.Fore_ID, tblforecast.Issued, tblforecast.Synopsis,tblforecast.Forecaster, tblusers.FirstName, tblusers.LastName FROM tblforecast INNER JOIN tblusers ON tblusers.UserNumber = tblforecast.forecaster WHERE ((tblforecast.Valid =) AND (tblforecast.Issued like '%01-07%' ))order by tblforecast.Issued DESC

Comment: @paxdiablo apparently, $valid worked if I don't put it inside the isset function

Comment: 24 comments to confirm an unset variable....

Comment: good teamwork guys - Clary, first line of Debug is not SO.

Comment: @user2310289 what is SO?

Comment: SO = http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @user2310289 Hahahaha! So that's so. :D

Answer (score 1):

try

```
AND (tblforecast.Issued like '%' + $filter + `%' ))  
                        // or whatever is right for PHP
```

but more importantly make sure that your variables are set before trying to use them in the sql.

Comment: Why? PHP is perfectly able to substitute variables within strings, is it not? In fact the error text shows that it works and, in addition, the error seems well before that point.

Comment: agreed. remember he is putting this all in a string, not writing directly executing SQL so what the OP had was fine.

Comment: Be nice to see what `$news` is ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the output of your `$news` variable contains:

```
WHERE ((tblforecast.Valid =) AND ...
                          ^^
                          ||
                      important bit
```

it's a simple matter of your `$type` variable not being set.

As an aside, the *first* thing you should always do when you get an error like this, is to actually print out the string you're using for the query. Ideally, MySQL should actually give you some of the context *before* the error point so it would be easier to figure out.

Comment: Yay. I'm hesitating to do something, but question as an answer from 313k rep. user makes me lost

Answer (score 0):

Clary,
 If code mentioned is exact with that you  using in your scripts , then I am not seeing any issue. I think that problem may be with variables used in a string.

I will Suggest you to use safe variable [parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) .

```
$news = "SELECT tblforecast.Fore_ID, tblforecast.Issued, 
      tblforecast.Synopsis,tblforecast.Forecaster, tblusers.FirstName,
      tblusers.LastName FROM tblforecast 
         INNER JOIN tblusers ON tblusers.UserNumber = tblforecast.forecaster 
      WHERE ((tblforecast.Valid = '{$type}') 
          AND (tblforecast.Issued like '%{$filter}%' ))
       order by tblforecast.Issued DESC";
```

Comment: Even better would be to switch to MySQLi and use prepared statements/bind variables if possible